# Upload Image in List

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

In my Sharepoint site, I have a list where users can enter his/her profile information, such as first name, last name, age, sex. In addition to this information, I want to let the users upload their images as well. When I create a view for this list, how can I let them show their image along with other information?

Can anyone tell me if there is any way to upload an image while adding new item to the list which will be use later in creating view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ways to approach this:

**Start with a picture library**

Add additional columns to the base set for storing the profile information you need. This is very simple and the list can be very simply managed using out-of-the-box views. Users are added by uploading their image and filling in their personal details.

**Start with a contact list**

Add a picture column for the user's image. This would require the extra step of the user having to upload their image somewhere. I would discount this option over the previous one as there are no significant advantages and you have to deal with the extra step.

**Use [My Sites](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101087481033.aspx)**

This gives each user their own private and public page and has the advantage of being initially populated from Active Directory. Users can upload a picture of themselves and you get other nice features as well.

However this won't give you the list you're looking for - you would need write a web part to query the profile data and display it as a list. Features to only display certain users and/or for editing a user's profile information may also be needed.

This can be a nice powerful solution but could also get complex quickly and may be overkill for what you need. My Sites should be planned carefully and require user education.

Answer (score 1):

http://sparqubepicturelite.codeplex.com - is newer and better version for SharePoint 2010 and it is not a web-part but a column.

Answer (score 0):

tried imageupload available at codeplex?

http://imageupload.codeplex.com/